# Can I traverse a linked list with its head node in its destructor?

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

This may seem like a stupid question, but the reason I ask is because I have this destructor:

```
list::~list()
{
    for (node* next = headByName->nextByName; headByName; headByName = next)
    {
        delete headByName;
    }
}
```

and valgrind still says that I have memory leaks. So I guess my real question is: is my destructor coded wrong, or is it just bad to destroy a list by traversing it with its head node?

Comment: That code be broken!

Comment: @CaptainObvlious XD I suppose I can see why you have so much reputation.

Comment: What user profile are you looking at? I have jack for reputation.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yours. Is 14,273 reputation nothing to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not doing the right thing.

1. You never change `next`, so `headByName` doesn't change after the first iteration.
2. If headByName is `nullptr` before the loop starts, you dereference a nullptr in your initialization.

Try this:

```
list::~list()
{
    while (headByName)
    {
      node* next = headByName->nextByName;
      delete headByName;
      headByName = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been told to use `for` loop's where ever possible. I guess this isn't the place for a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Since you commented about the preference of for loops, being a fan of for and I use it wherever possible, I would like to write how this can be achieved with  a for loop:

```
for(node* next; headByName; headByName = next)
{   next = headByName->nextByName;
    delete headByName;
}
```

Comment: Would this be any less efficient than @ronalchn 's while loop?

Comment: @Larrimus It is the same performance-wise, the same order of statements, but written differently. I love using for loops because they make the code shorter. The above code could be even written entirely one line with the for, but I dont want to write "unfamiliar" and probably non-recommended things :)

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't give you +15 reputation by marking your solution as the correct answer, but have an upvote. Thank you!

Comment: Oh I knew that, it is not a problem, I just wanted to share, thanks :)